# Phonegap jquery ajax form submit not working

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am a bit of a newbie to Phonegap and jQuery, but have researched how to submit a form via jQuery ajax.  This code works in a webpage, but fails in the android emulator when built and installed by Phonegap.  As you can see I have set the `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;`. When I test this in the emulator, the screen flashes a couple of times, the form is cleared as if the page was reloaded, and nothing is written to the server.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="enter.css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>

    <script>
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
          // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!

          $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });

        function doform()
        {

            var datas = $("#enteractivity").serialize();
            $.ajax({

              url: "http://www.scottallencarter.com/llp/record.logactivity",
              data: datas,
              async: false,
              cache: false,
              dataType: 'text',
              type: 'POST',
              jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
              timeout: 120000,
              crossDomain: true,
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('error');

                },
              success: function(msg){ 
                    alert('done success');
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="enter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page1">
        <div data-theme="c" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Activity
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="enteractivity" name="enteractivity" onsubmit="doform()">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="activityspecifics">
                            Activity
                        </label>
                        <input name="activityspecifics" id="activityspecifics" placeholder="Enter Activity" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="category">
                        Category:
                    </label>
                    <select name="category" data-theme="c">
                        <option value="">(choose one)</option>
                        ...
                        <option value="Test">Test</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="activityInCategory">
                        Specific Category:
                    </label>
                    <select name="activityInCategory" data-theme="c">
                        <option value="AddSubCategory">+ Add New Specific Category</option>
                        <option value="">------------</option>
                        ...
                    </select>

                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1-1-1-1-1">
                <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="true">
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="left" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Also when the form does submit from a webpage, it always returns error.  Not sure what I need to return from the server side for success.

Comment: Changed the ajax code to the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the issue.  It was actually a misunderstanding of how jquery mobile works.  The page with the form was linked from another page, and the default jquery mobile behavior is to load the page via ajax and ignore the head section.  The script to submit the form was in the head tags.  Moving the script for ajax form submit to the bottom of the body tag in the page fixed the issue. Thank you for the help, and I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if Phonegap just read the `index.html` file from the first run..

so, move any `ajax` form submission on `form.html` to `index.html` at the bottom of the body tag.

its work for me

Answer (score -1):

You cannot mix *POST* with *JSONP*. *JSONP* is using *GET*.
However, the server has to support *JSONP*. Looking at your example, this should already be the case.

**Try this:**
Here is a working example, I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.yoursite.com',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: datas,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (json) {
        // Do some stuff
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus) {
        // Error handling
    }
});
```

---

**Edit:**
FYI, if you are sending data cross-domain via *POST* you will always get an error, because the browser discards the response (although it exists).
You can create a local html page (with your example code) and open it with your browser.
Afterwards check the traffic with *fiddler* and *firebug*.
AFAIK, you can only receive data from a cross-domain request with *JSONP*.

**Best regards**

Comment: Changed the code with no luck.  Does not even send a request to the specified server from the android emulator.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you access the internet from the android emulator? Maybe there is a problem with *DHCP* and/or the bridged network. Best regards.

Comment: @NightlyCoder You understanding is wrong. JSONP exists only for GET and not for POST.

Comment: @Anil: That's what I've written. Look at my first sentence "You cannot mix/use POST with JSONP. JSONP is using GET". And then one of my last sentences "... via POST you will always get an error ...".